# nested SELECT in INSERT sql statement

Tags: syntax-error, sql, insert-statement

Can someone tell me why this doesnt work?

```
INSERT INTO Medical_History (pid, grafts, allergies,  diseases, surgearies, treatment)
VALUES ((SELECT pid FROM Pet WHERE pet_name='Jack' AND cid=(SELECT cid FROM Customer WHERE last_name='Iwannidis' AND first_name='Giwrgos')),
       'grafts', 'allergies', 'diseases', 'surgearies', treatments');
```

I get a syntax error:

```
unrecognized token "');"
```

Comment: well... it does work if you add the missing ' in 'statements'. lol
Gordon got a better formatted syntax tho. I grant him the answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `select` nested in the `values` statement looks wrong (and I'm not sure that all databases accept it).  A more typical way to express this is:

```
INSERT INTO Medical_History (pid, grafts, allergies,  diseases, surgearies, treatment)
    SELECT pid, 'grafts', 'allergies', 'diseases', 'surgearies', 'treatments'
    FROM Pet
    WHERE pet_name='Jack' AND
          cid=(SELECT cid
               FROM Customer
               WHERE last_name='Iwannidis' AND first_name='Giwrgos'
              );
```

This is particularly important if the subquery returns more than one value.  Then the query is likely to get an error.

Comment: After i fixed the missing ' in 'treatments' it worked like charm. But obviously your syntax seems much more legit. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @LePhleg . . . I've rephrased the answer.  In general, I just don't use `values` because it is totally redundant, and `select` is more versatile.

Answer (score 2):

I had a syntax error because I had forgotten the quotes (`'`) on 'treatments'.

Comment: true, but irrelevant.

Comment: that was the syntax error @DanBracuk :)